# Loading an image into a scaleable DIV

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to use thumbnailviewer2.js to load an image into a div that is set to take up the width of the current browser window. The image loads in fine but doesn't then scale to the size of the current DIV width.

My code looks like this

HTML:

```
<div id="loadarea2">
  <img class="mainimage" src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="front image" />
</div>

<div id="thumbs">
  <ul class="categoryitems">
    <li>
      <a href="images/slide1.jpg" rel="enlargeimage" rev="targetdiv:loadarea2,trigger:click, preload:yes" >
        <img src="images/thumb01.jpg" border="0"/>
      </a>
   </li>
```

CSS:

```
#loadarea2 {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */    
    min-width:800px;
    background-color:#000000;
}

.mainimage {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */    
    min-width:800px;
}
```

Dose anyone have an idea as to where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `mainimage` or the one in the `li`? Do you have any CSS for the one in the `li`?

Answer (score 0):

Set the width for `mainimage` to `inherit`.

```
.mainimage
{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: inherit;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */    
    min-width:800px;
}
```

Comment: Or `width:100%` because they're equivalent. And there is no reason for the pre-IE line

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the answer but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Here's the complete CSS, with sample LI code



.categoryitems li
{
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
float:right;
margin-left:0px;
color:#FFFFFF;
padding-right:20px;
display:block;
}

#thumbs
{
 float:left;
clear:both;
width:800px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#loadarea2
{
width:100%;
height:auto;
width: auto\9; /* ie8 */ 
min-width:800px;
background-color:#000000;
}

.mainimage
{
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width:inherit;
min-width:800px;
}